# How does the language standard define uint8_t when CHAR_BIT > 8?

Tags: c

I don't have any platform with `CHAR_BIT > 8` at hand.

So I changed the related preprocessor definitions in file `limits.h`:

```
#define CHAR_BIT      16          /* number of bits in a char */
#define SCHAR_MIN   (-32768)      /* minimum signed char value */
#define SCHAR_MAX     32767       /* maximum signed char value */
#define UCHAR_MAX     0xffff      /* maximum unsigned char value */
```

Then, when including file `stdint.h`, I'd expect to see that `uint8_t` was no longer a viable type.

Yet it is.

How does the language standard settle this?

Comment: *These types are optional.* Changing files related to the compiler will probably result in a non-functioning compiler.

Comment: @2501: Do you mean that they are not part of the language standard?

Comment: Read: *7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types*

Comment: Only the ISO committee is not allowed to assume that a byte is an octet.  Whomever creates a compiler for a specific target architecture and writes the .h files for it never has that problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file `limits.h` is not a configuration file for your compiler; it is a mechanism via which the implementation provides information to you. Your compiler *knows* that `char` has 8 bits and that `uint8_t` is `unsigned char`; it doesn't need to read the `limits.h` file to find that out.

If you want a car analogy, hammering a nail through your fuel gauge won't prevent you from running the tank dry.

Comment: Or rewriting "100" over the "50" on your speedometer won't get you to your destination twice as fast.

Comment: Haha, +1 for the analogy. As I explain in a comment, I did not change the definitions in order to emulate a different architecture and test it. I changed them in order to see if `uint8_t` was still defined. So I don't think that the first statement answers my question. But the second one does. May I ask how the compiler knows that `char` has 8 bits. Doesn't there have to be a definition somewhere? Or is the compiler executable already built (compiled and linked) with that definition as part of its own source code? Thanks.

Comment: @barakmanos The C99 standard draft says that a byte must be at least 8-bit wide, because `<limits.h>` contains a macro `CHAR_BIT` which yields the number of bits per byte, and is guaranteed to be at least 8.

Comment: @Module: I do not understand, how does that answer the question of how `uint8_t` is defined when `CHAR_BIT > 1`?

Comment: @barakmanos it depends on the compiler, but yes, for a well-organized compiler there will be somewhere in its own source code where the sizes of each of the C types are defined, possibly for multiple targets if the compiler supports multiple targets, and then these are compiled into the compiler. For example, Clang has https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/lib/Basic/Targets.cpp